# Appium not work with Android default Web Browser

Tags: android, mobile, browser, appium

How to configure Appium to work with Android default Web Browser for mobile web testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, worked for me

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

set your capabilities for version

Comment: One more notice is that Appium not works with non AOSP browser (which replace by Manufacture's browser on Samsung, HTC or LG... devices).

Comment: How is Appium related to this answer? I don't understand where exactly Appiums goes into work here, looks like you use driver (WebDriver) implementation with RemoteWebDriver...